# Word counter -- Batch

Tags: windows, powershell, batch, script, open-source

I want to make a batch-script that counts the times that the word "parent" appear in the file,

```
http://api.github.com/repos/godzillamesel/disclovestory/commits
```

I'm currenly downloading this file with:

```
cd "$env:programfiles\DiscLovestory\sys\update" 
Remove-Item "git_commit.log" 
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol =  tls12, tls11, tls" 
wget -O git_commit.log http://api.github.com/repos/godzillamesel/disclovestory/commits 
pause
```

Having this is file is also gonna be needed as a "update-note" to the user. This script went straight to powershell, since i don't know how bitsadmin works, but if you also know how that should work, be my guest to help me out! As my script is based to be a batch-only script.

I want the output to go to: `"%programfiles%\DiscLovestory\sys\update\version.log"` and also in registry:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\DiscLovestory" /v DisplayVersion /t REG_SZ /d
```

In both output places it should be enough to just put version as follow: "x.xx" without quotations.

And if you wanna follow up on the script, or use it, be my guest. It is open-source at: `https://github.com/godzillamesel/disclovestory`

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you asking to have the script written for you?

Comment: no, I'm not asking to have the script written for me, but mainly to let  me see alternatives. I am pretty new to batch-scripting.. And i have googled my ass of to this for around 20 hours, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Since git_commit.log is in`.json` format use PowerShell for parents count `((Get-Content .\git_commit.log | ConvertFrom-Json).parents).count` returns 19 here. Otherwise it's unclear to me where the version number should come from, there is none in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally figured it out. We used a script in C that a friend of mine made. Was not was i was searching for, but it works.
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LINESZ 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 3){
        printf("Usage: count.exe <stack> <needle>\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    char* stack = argv[1];
    char* needle = argv[2];
    int count = 0;
    char buff[LINESZ];
    FILE *fin = fopen (stack, "r");
    if (fin != NULL) {
        while (fgets (buff, LINESZ, fin)) {
            if(strstr(buff,needle)){
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        fclose (fin);
    }
    printf("%d\n",count);
}
```

It is compiled to https://github.com/godzillamesel/disclovestory/blob/master/scripts/sys/update/count.exe if you are gonna need it.
count.exe

Comment: (1) There’s no such thing as “a script in C”.  If it’s compilable, it’s called a program. (2) How is this any better than the `findstr` answer?  Does this count multiple occurrences on a line?  Does it ignore words like “apparently”, “grandparent” and “parenting”?

Comment: i have not tested the count program yet if it ignores the "family" of a word, it is not my need really because it gives me what i need for my update script.grandparent will not appaer.But it counts how many occurrences the word will appear in the "log-file"

Comment: tested now, it takes the all words with parents in it :/ but as i said, for my use it works good enough.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
@echo off
set /a COUNT=0
for /f %%i in ('findstr /i /c:"parent" commits.txt') do (
  set /a COUNT=COUNT + 1
)
echo "parent" words count: %COUNT% 
pause
```

Referrence:[how to get the word count within batch file in MS DOS and manipulate to exit loop](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29003570/how-to-get-the-word-count-within-batch-file-in-MS-DOS-and-manipulate-to-exit-loop.html)

Comment: This will **not** count multiple matches on a line, and catch possibly unwanted variants `grandparent` or `parents` This will exclude the variants `findstr /i "\<parent\>" commits.txt`